# My Acer Z160 has a weird problem with flashing and reset

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing, malware, system-error, stock-rom

my friend's phone had an error on his phone(Acer z160 not rooted), all the applications crash at start-up. It came to my mind that I had to do a factory reset via stock recovery. After the reset, I restarted the phone and the error was still there. I decided to flash the stock ROM
(Acer_AV052_Z160_1.015.00_EMEA_GEN1) using the "SP_Flash_Tool_exe_Windows_v5.1516.00" and the flash was successful. Rebooted the phone again, and the error was still there. In fact, the phone's password/pattern is still there, the wallpaper hasn't changed and apps are still there. What happened? What should i do? Could you please help me. Any help would be appreciated

Here's the error on a video----->https://youtu.be/kJGMsVhHmWI
Here's the photo of the flashing---->https://i.imgsafe.org/abfd650013.jpg

Answer (score 0):

That means your device's eMMC is (Write Protected), Which means that it won't accept any changes you do, This is a common problem in MTK based devices, Actually you have to replace the eMMC chip by a new one, But you can also try this,

1. Run SPFT and Load "Scatter" File,
2. Go to "Format" tab,
3. Don't mess with any options there,
4. Click "Start" then Plug your phone,
5. Wait until the Format process finish,
6. Now just try to flash the phone again with SPFT,

NOTE: After this process your phone won't have IMEI anymore, But that's not a problem since there is a lot of ways to restore it, Just check this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22493K0URz4).

If the above guide didn't help fixing your phone, then as i said before, eMMC needs to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Mr. Mohamed! I really appreciated it :)

I forgot to mention Mr. Mohamed, my friend told me that this error/crashing  happened after he downloaded a music from a website. Supposedly a website with a malware, since he isn't a techy guy. Now, may I ask Sir, is it possible that a malware did this to his phone or is it just a weird coincidence...